# ListBox Group Binding not displaying header

Tags: c#, wpf, xaml, listbox

I've been following this [guide](http://wpf.2000things.com/2014/01/13/985-displaying-expandable-groups-within-a-listbox/) (among other resources) and have the ListBox grouping my list of Users successfully. The problem now is two-fold;

1. The header of each group is not displaying what it is grouping by (at present, just an int).
2. I would like, if possible, for the header to be a lookup. (I'm using Entity Framework, so this could be made redundant by using an `Include(u => u.Ref_Department)` on the query to get the list of Users.)

The data is as follows;

**Users**
idUser
id_Department
Name

**Department**
idDepartment
DepartmentName

The XAML;

```
<Grid>
    <Grid.Resources>
        <CollectionViewSource x:Key="lsUsers" Source="{Binding RelativeSource={RelativeSource AncestorType={x:Type Window}}, Path=_Users}">
            <CollectionViewSource.GroupDescriptions>
                <PropertyGroupDescription PropertyName="id_Department"/>
            </CollectionViewSource.GroupDescriptions>
        </CollectionViewSource>
    </Grid.Resources>
    <ListBox ItemsSource="{Binding Source={StaticResource lsUsers}}">
        <ListBox.GroupStyle>
            <GroupStyle>
                <GroupStyle.ContainerStyle>
                    <Style TargetType="{x:Type GroupItem}">
                        <Setter Property="Template">
                            <Setter.Value>
                                <ControlTemplate>
                                    <Expander Header="{Binding id_Department}" IsExpanded="True">
                                        <ItemsPresenter/>
                                    </Expander>
                                </ControlTemplate>
                            </Setter.Value>
                        </Setter>
                    </Style>
                </GroupStyle.ContainerStyle>
            </GroupStyle>
        </ListBox.GroupStyle>
    </ListBox>
</Grid>
```

`_Users` is a `List<Users>` property of the class, which is obviously working fine anyway, it's just the header that is falling down for some reason and I don't really understand why.

There is a highlight/warning on the `<Expander Header...` line under `id_Department` that says "Cannot resolve symbol 'id_Department' due to unknown DataContext"

**Update**
If I change the `<Expander Header...` binding to `Name`, it displays the id_Department. Not sure how/why that works and I'm not sure that it'll help with Point 1 above.

Answer (score 0):

while Using GroupStyle you have only the following Binding Propoerties:
**Name:** which is the Name of group property that make the grouping based on
**ItemCount:** which is the Rows Count of each grouping record
and if you want another property based on grouping item you should use `Converter` but when using:

```
{Binding Converter="{StaticResource yourConverter}"
```

consider that the value of `Converter` is `CollectionViewGroup` which is the list of objects or rows that is in the grouped base item.

Answer (score 0):

As @safi implies, because the `GroupItem` is what is being styled you only have the **Name** and **ItemCount** properties to bind to.

It sounds like you are trying to group by department but want to see the department name instead of the ID. Therefore you should add a string **Department** property to your `Users` class and group on that instead of the department ID property.

You can control the ordering of the groups by changing the `SortDescriptions` of the collection view. For example, if you want to group by department name but still see departments listed in ID order rather than alphabetically then group by the name and also sort by the ID, like this:

```
ICollectionView view = CollectionViewSource.GetDefaultView(_Users);
view.GroupDescriptions.Add(new PropertyGroupDescription("DepartmentName"));
view.SortDescriptions.Add(new SortDescription("DepartmentId", ListSortDirection.Ascending));
view.SortDescriptions.Add(new SortDescription("UserName", ListSortDirection.Ascending));
```

I've used different property names here but you get the idea.